# Insert multi-dimensional Array with both strings and numbers into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I've seen many examples looping through array using foreach and implode function to build sql string for MySQL Insert query. However, all those examples assume that all values in the Array and all columns in the MySQL table are either string or a number. Is there a way to do something similar, but with an Array that has both strings and numbers and is to be inserted into MySQL table that has string and number columns?

```
$insertArr[] = array(
        'order_id' => $orderID, 
        'user_id' => $userID,         
        'price' => $price, 
        'quantity' => $quantity);

$colNames = "( " . implode(", ",array_keys($insertArr[0])) . " )";
foreach ( $insertArr as $row )
{        
    $colValuesArr[] = "( '" . implode("', '", $row) . "' )";
}
$colValues = implode(", ", $colValuesArr);
$strsql = "INSERT INTO tbl_orders $colNames 
            VALUES $colValues";
```

The code above is not working right, because `order_id` and `user_id` are strings and `price` and `quantity` are numbers. Imploding it with quotes and commas assumes that all values are strings, imploding it without quotes assumes that all values are numbers. Is there a way, without having to loop through every single element in the array, to do this?

Comment: The variable `$strsql` has invalid SQL syntax.  That could explain why the code is not working.

Comment: MySQL is fine with numbers being quoted.  If you want to keep it simple, just quote everything.  (But remember to escape your data!)  Or, look into prepared statements; in the long run, they will make things much easier for you.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, what is wrong with the $strsql SQL syntax? It seems good to me. I printed it, don't see anything wrong with it. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the way you want to handle things, & you do not want to loop through arrays or use prepared statements, I think this should work. I reformatted your code a bit but the overall logic is still intact. The logic I added is to basically create two separate arrays. One for numerical values. The other for text values:

```
// Test data.
$orderID = 'testorderid';
$userID = 'testuserid';
$price = 7.99;
$quantity = 2;

// Create the text values array.
$insertArrText[] = array('order_id' => $orderID, 'user_id' => $userID);

// Create the numerical values array.
$insertArrNumerical[] = array('price' => $price, 'quantity' => $quantity);

// Get the array keys & merge them into one combined array.
$array_keys = array_merge(array_keys($insertArrText[0]), array_keys($insertArrNumerical[0]));

// Set the column names.
$colNames = "( " . implode(", ", $array_keys) . " )";

// Loop through the '$insertArrText'
foreach ($insertArrText as $key => $row ) {

  // Set the numerical values.
  $numerical_values = implode(", ", $insertArrNumerical[$key]);

  // Set the text values.
  $text_values = "'" . implode("', '", $row) . "'";

  // Set the column values array.
  $colValuesArr[] = "(" . $text_values . "," . $numerical_values . ")";
}

// Set the column values string.
$colValues = implode(", ", $colValuesArr);

// Create the MySQL query.
$strsql = "INSERT"
        . " INTO tbl_orders " . $colNames
        . " VALUES " . $colValues
        ;

// Echo the output for testing.
echo $strsql;
```

The output of that script is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_orders ( order_id, user_id, price, quantity ) VALUES ('testorderid', 'testuserid',7.99, 2)
```

**EDIT** Here is a reworking using [`gettype`](https://www.php.net/gettype) to detect string type. More flexible & robust. This is using test data of course, but should be easily adaptable to real world scenarios.

```
// Test data.
$orderID = 'testorderid';
$userID = 'testuserid';
$price = 7.99;
$quantity = 2;

// Create an array map based on strings & MySQL DB field values.
$array_map = array();
$array_map['orderID'] = 'order_id';
$array_map['userID'] = 'user_id';
$array_map['price'] = 'price';
$array_map['quantity'] = 'quantity';

// Create the text arrays.
$insertArrText = array();
$insertArrNumerical = array();

// Set arrays for text and numberical types.
$text_types = array('string');
$numerical_types = array('double','integer');

// Lopop through the array map & assign values based on type.
foreach ($array_map as $array_map_key => $array_map_value) {
  if (in_array(gettype($$array_map_key), $text_types)) {
    $insertArrText[0][$array_map_value] = $$array_map_key;
  }
  else if (in_array(gettype($$array_map_key), $numerical_types)) {
    $insertArrNumerical[0][$array_map_value] = $$array_map_key;
  }
}

// Get the array keys & merge them into one combined array.
$array_keys = array_merge(array_keys($insertArrText[0]), array_keys($insertArrNumerical[0]));

// Set the column names.
$colNames = "( " . implode(", ", $array_keys) . " )";

// Loop through the '$insertArrText'
foreach ($insertArrText as $key => $row ) {

  // Set the numerical values.
  $numerical_values = implode(", ", $insertArrNumerical[$key]);

  // Set the text values.
  $text_values = "'" . implode("', '", $row) . "'";

  // Set the column values array.
  $colValuesArr[] = "(" . $text_values . "," . $numerical_values . ")";
}

// Set the column values string.
$colValues = implode(", ", $colValuesArr);

// Create the MySQL query.
$strsql = "INSERT"
        . " INTO tbl_orders " . $colNames
        . " VALUES " . $colValues
        ;

// Echo the output for testing.
echo $strsql;
```

And the output of this code is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_orders ( order_id, user_id, price, quantity ) VALUES ('testorderid', 'testuserid',7.99, 2)
```

Comment: this might work if it's just for a specific purpose. However, I am trying to build a function that I could use anytime, and every time the array might be different, different value types.

Comment: how would you use prepared statements?

Comment: gettype is an option, because I can just do it on the first row, as it is assumed that all of the next rows will have the same types. that way i don't have to loop through every single element in the array, just the first row. i'll try that.

Comment: JakeGould, do you know if the performance of the query is worse if I use PDO prepared statements rather then the method above?

Answer (score 0):

Use array_map:

```
$row = array_map(function ($a) {
  if (is_numeric($a)) return $a;
  else return "'".$a."'";
},$row);
```

Assuming your data is safe, otherwise please use something like mysql_real_escape or use PDO prepared statements.